# Using weights in downstream microbiome analysis

Tags: r, weighted, phyloseq

I am working on microbiome analysis. I have a metadata containing weights for each participants, which means every participant may represent different number of participants. The weights could help better balance the covariants between comparison groups (which were currently quite unbalanced), so I do want to take the weights into further consideration. I wonder is it possible to add weights when conducting downstream analysis like alpha diversity, beta diversity (especially using adonis), differential abundance analysis and related visualization? Any suggestions on packages or tools or something else are welcomed!

Currently, I learned that we could use svyglm on alpha diversity (using these indices as outcome variables) and ZINB could use weights. Are there any other options possible? And what about beta diversity?